# Subdataset - total rows in the List

Tags: jasper-reports

I have created a *subdataset* in my main report and using that to create a list. The list displays all the rows from my dataset, but is there a way to place a total number of rows count in the list component.

With the `$V{REPORT_COUNT}` variable, i can get the total count but its repeated multiple times (as the number of rows in the sub dataset )

Answer (score 1):

As noted in the answer by user jmurray here: http://community.jaspersoft.com/questions/514827/row-count

In your `subDataSet`, create a variable:

```
<variable name="ROW_COUNTER" class="java.lang.Integer" incrementType="Report" calculation="Count">
    <variableExpression><![CDATA[new java.lang.Integer(1)]]></variableExpression>
    <initialValueExpression><![CDATA[new java.lang.Integer(0)]]></initialValueExpression>
</variable>
```

Then somewhat like what Mike Noland has in his answer, create a list that points to the same `subDataSet` as the original list with a `textField`:

```
<textField>
    <reportElement isPrintRepeatedValues="false" x="0" y="0" width="100" height="11"/>
    <textFieldExpression><![CDATA[new java.lang.Integer($V{ROW_COUNTER}.intValue()+1)]]></textFieldExpression>
</textField>
```

This creates a zero based counter that holds the total count of items. Then by telling the report not to print repeats, you end up with a single item that represents the total number of items in your subDataSet

Answer (score 0):

Create A second **List** set it to use the same dataset  and put only the `$V{REPORT_COUNT}` in it. Set the **position type** to float

Second option is to use the **Table** in place of the **List** as it has the banding to allow for a header or footer of your dataset

Comment: List approach you mentioned didnt work. I set the position type of the text field to float. is that right?

Comment: no you should set the position type of the list box as float (so it would be the next hing after you first last box.